# Execute a function periodically in 10 milliseconds in C++

Tags: c++, events, visual-c++, thread-sleep

I have a C++ function which is to be executed periodically once in every 10 milliseconds. The function is to be executed at the start of every 10 milliseconds slot. One option to implement this is using *Sleep* function, but it is not guaranteed of executing the function after exactly 10 milliseconds. Are there any alternatives to get this working? I am using Windows 7 OS.

Comment: You can't have better realtime capabilities as the operating system offers, besides using a separate hardware timer.

Comment: Use the multimedia timer functions. You can change the tick rate from the default 64 hz to 1000 hz (or in this case, perhaps 100 hz) via timeBeginPeriod(), and set a timer to trigger an event or perform a call back every 10 ms. [multimedia timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd743609(v=vs.85).aspx)